# Magmatic sensor's error in MPU9150

Tags: sensor, c

I coded the following program to get the acceleration, gyro, and magnetic sensor values by using a MPU9150 that is connected to a Raspberry Pi 2 via I2C.
I can get the proper acceleration and gyro values, but the magnetic sensor value is not correct.

I displayed the register value of magnetic X axis (16bit). The High byte is 0x00 or 0xff, and the low byte is consequence value [0x00,0xff]. So, I think that the High byte of magnetic has problem. Please let me know how to resolve it.

**Output**

Ex.1: `lsb=0e,msb=00`
Ex.2: `lsb=12,msb=00`
Ex.3: `lsb=1d,msb=ff`

**Code**

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>

#define MPU9150_ADDRESS (0x68)     
#define MPU9150_REG_PWR_MGMT_1 (0x6b) 
#define MPU9150_INT_PIN_CFG (0x37)   
#define MPU9150_GYRO_CFG (0x1b)
#define MPU9150_REG_DATA_START (0x3b) 
#define M_I2C_ADDRESS (0x0c)         
#define M_CNTL (0x0A)
#define M_REG_DATA_START (0x03)     

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("MPU9150 starting\n");
    // Setup Wiring Pi
    wiringPiSetup();
    // Open an I2C connection
    int fd = wiringPiI2CSetup(MPU9150_ADDRESS); 

    // MPU6050_REG_PWR_MGMT_1
    wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_PWR_MGMT_1, 0x00);

    wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd,MPU9150_INT_PIN_CFG, 0x02);

    wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd,MPU9150_GYRO_CFG, 0x10);

    int fd2 = wiringPiI2CSetup(M_I2C_ADDRESS);
    wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd2,M_CNTL, 0x01);

    while(1) {
        uint8_t msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START);
        uint8_t lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+1);
        float accelX = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+2);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+3);
        float  accelY = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+4);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+5)
        float  accelZ = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+6);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+7);
        float  temp = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+8);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+9);
        float  gyroX = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+10);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+11);
        float  gyroY = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+12);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+13);
        float  gyroZ = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd2,M_CNTL, 0x01);
        delay(10);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd2, M_REG_DATA_START);
        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd2, M_REG_DATA_START+1);
        float  magX =  ((int16_t msb << 8 )| lsb ;

        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd2, M_REG_DATA_START+2);
        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd2, M_REG_DATA_START+3);
        float  magY = ((int16_t msb << 8 )| lsb ;

        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd2, M_REG_DATA_START+4);
        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd2, M_REG_DATA_START+5);
        float  magZ = ((int16_t msb << 8 )| lsb ;


        printf("lsb=%x,msb=%x\n",lsb,msb);

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any Arduino involved ...

Comment: You probably need to read all the bytes as a single datum (i.e. in one read).  Check the device datasheet.

Comment: ＞ You probably need to read all the bytes as a single datum (i.e. in one read). Sorry , I don't know the meaning of the above your comments. Is the meaning that I should use wiringPiI2CReadReg16 ? But the result did not changed.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet for the MPU9150 indicates that the magnetic compass is the AKM AK8975.  Looking through the [datasheet for the AK8975](http://www.akm.com/akm/en/file/datasheet/AK8975.pdf) it seems that the output is MSB first.  However, it seems from your code that LSB is read first.